# Windows 8 password protected apps and the Windows store

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps

In the past, I experienced difficulties publishing password protected iOS apps. iOS representative were worried we were trying to ‘sell’ the content independently. Anyhow, we are thinking of deploying a password protected Windows app but we want to find out if Windows review process is strict about things like that (we don’t have any experience publishing on the Windows Store).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suppose by "password protected" app you mean an app which requires the user to have his own login credentials in order to fully access (or use) the app. In this case you will need to provide Microsoft with credentials to test the app during the certification process. Here's a quote from the [certification requirements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694083.aspx):

> **1.2 Your app must be testable when it is submitted to the Windows Store**
>
> If, for any reason, it is not possible to test some parts of your app,
>   your app may fail this requirement. For example, if your app requires
>   login credentials, provide us with a working demo account using the
>   Notes to Tester field. If your app requires access to a server, tell
>   us what we need to do to verify that it's working correctly. If your
>   app allows a user to add a gift card balance, give us a gift card
>   number that can be used in the testing.